# What is the meaning of the rm -fv command?? using it for csf installation

Tags: linux, computer-science

I want to know what exactly the following command means ??

```
rm -fv csf.tgz
```

I'm typing this command as the first step for installing csf on my virtualmin, but I dont know the exact meaning. I just now copied and pasted it.

Comment: rm is remove,   "- f is force as in ignore non-exsistent file"  "-v is verbose" as per the man page of rm shows a list of files processed . you are basically deleting files from your system

Comment: but csf.tgz is not present in the system ! i have to download it

Comment: @SivaprasathV so wht is the fun of writing this command

Comment: may be removing any previous files from the system...for downloading programs you use something like sudo apt-get update then sudo apt-get install repository_name or just the second part.... if you dont know what a function is for try typing man function-name to get the manual pages for it

Comment: the above function removes a tarball file or a gzipped tar file thats it. its not installing anything

Comment: thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

**rm -rf / – Deletes Everything!**

Never use this command in your Linux computer because it deletes every file in your system.

sudo - sudo (Super User DO) is generally used as a prefix of some command that only superuser are allowed to run.

rm – Remove the following files.

-rf – Run rm recursively (delete all files and folders inside the specified folder) and force-remove all files without prompting you.

/ – Tells rm to start at the root directory, which contains all the files on your computer and all mounted media devices, including remote file shares and removable drives.